# Problemas con xammp

Tags: xampp

Estoy instalando xammp (Ya lo e realizado antes y funcionó bien) y al parecer todo esta bien pero cuando intento ingresar a localhost/phpmyadmin obtengo el siguiente error Not Found
The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.

y cuando entro solo al localhost sale la pagina de apache diciendo haciendo el testing 123. Alguien puede ayudarme, debo cambiar algo en el config o algo asi.

Comment: Revisa desde servicios que no tengas algun otr servicio de apache instalado, y si encuentras el de Apache detenido o manual, dale clic derecho e iniciar, a ver si te da algun error.

Comment: como puedo saber que otro servicio  de apache tengo instalado, o sabes si existe alguna manera de desinstalarlos todos ?

Comment: Quizá sea el puerto. No recuerdo muy bien, pero en alguna ocasión tuve que poner http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin...

Comment: Lo del puerto ya lo hice, puse 8080 y nada me sale otro error